# How to group by a column with null values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
C1   | C2
-----|----
23   | 10
null | 10
23   | 10
24   | 10
24   | 10
```

I want group by C1 and calculate null's C2 value in both 23 and 24's sum(C2)

```
SELECT C1, sum(C2) FROM table 
GROUP BY C1
```

query return this table:

```
C1   | C2
-----|----
23   | 20
null | 10
24   | 20
```

but I want this:

```
C1   | C2
-----|----
23   | 30
24   | 30
```

is it possible to get a result like that?

Comment: where c1 is not null

Comment: why c2 is 30 for both?.. how do you decide to which C1 [23;24] you should add null C@ value?..

Comment: yes, and c2 of null c1, be used in all other rows sum calculation

Comment: @VaoTsun, All null c2 values should be used in sum calculation of other rows.

Comment: which means all C2 values where C1 is null are added to ALL other C2 summaries grouped by C1?.. In other words duplicated/triplicated etc?..

Comment: @VaoTsun, yes, thats right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY` as before, but do also add a sub-select that sums c2 for all null valued c1's:

```
select c1, sum(c2) + (select sum(c2) from table where c1 is null)
from table
where c1 is not null
group by c1
```

Core-99 ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (I tested in MySQL):

```
SELECT C1, sum(C2) + @runtot AS sum
FROM (SELECT @runtot:= SUM(C2) from mytable t where t.C1 IS NULL) c,
mytable
WHERE C1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY C1
```

Comment: could you explain what does this query do? because I should change it to postgresql, thanks

Comment: Basically you iterate the table once (inner select) and you calculate the sum of all C2 for which C1 is null. The result is stored into a temp variable, namely runtot. Then you iterate the table once more (in the outer select), taking into account only the records for which C1 is not null. To these values you then add the content of the temp variable that you calculate before.

Comment: This doesn't work in Postgres (or any DBMS other than MySQL). Plus it is a very complicated (and non-portable) way of writing the same thing as jarlh did.